# Outdated community ads are being shown

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

**Update:**

After some [detective work by @barbarabeeton](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59029149#59029149) it turned out the problem is not the display of downvote/deleted ads but that old ads from the last year get displayed.

Can the ads please be switched over to this years ads?

---

<s>Please don't show community ads which have been downvoted and deleted during the voting phase.</s>

For example this ad for an outdated event is currently displayed on tex.se

[image]

The corresponding meta post has been downvoted and deleted during the voting phase: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8806/36296

[image]

Why is it nevertheless shown on the site? The announcement post said:

> [...] they must have a minimum score of 6 at the time the post was closed/locked for submissions.

Comment: Uh, no.  I think the problem is that the 2020 ads are still in effect, and the turnover to the 2021 ads hasn't yet been activated.  In either case, it's despicable, as it denigrates the advertised organization through no fault of its own.  It would probably be actionable for legal liability if the organization were so inclined.

Comment: Turned out the displayed ad is not downvoted/deleted, but still from the previous year... not sure what is worse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Community Ads will be switched to the 2021 ads soon - I'm not sure on the specific timeline but it should be this month (September). In the near term, the solution is to delete that answer, which should prevent the ad from appearing until we do switch over to the new ads (some caching may apply). It's highly voted so you will likely need to flag the post for a mod to delete - feel free to link to this answer if you're not certain that the mods will agree.

I understand that the delays to get out the new Community Ads are long but we appreciate your patience with this. Hopefully this addresses your concern until the ads can be updated!